Is there still way bring down the missing light in relation to what it says in Igerret Hateshuvah
BH
Hi, I was once in an Iggeret Hateshuvah class on Tanya and our teacher was reading the first perek and where it says that if you miss doing a positive mitvah you are never able to fix it as it says meuvat lo Yuchal letaken although our teacher said although if you connected to a Rebbe(specifically believe he was referring to the Lubavitcher Rebbe) there is still an ability and hope to bring down the missing light that wasn’t brought down by doing the positive mitzvah.
So what is he talking about since that would totally contradict what it says in the Iggeret HaYeshuvah no? What is the source of this?

See footnote 10 here

To summarize the footnote @shmosel referenced: in Likkutei Torah, Balak 73d, the Alter Rebbe states that filling in that missing light requires a powerful level of teshuvah described by the phrase "From the depths I call to You." In ibid. Rosh Hashanah 54a ff, he expands on this: the Supernal "depth" is G-d's Will, far higher than the "chain of evolution" that is revealed in the human will; by accessing that level,, one can fill in what was left out by failing to do a positive mitzvah. The analogy: when a river dries up and needs to be refilled, one digs deeper into the spring that feeds it.

One should be very cautious with Hassidic ideology that holds Kosher Jews as inherently weak, sinful, and unable to "fix themselves" unless they admit the necessity of the mediation by a human saint.

@AlBerko One should be very cautious of misinterpreting Chassidic sources to be saying that Kosher Jews are "inherently weak, sinful." And of misinterpreting "guidance" as "mediation."

Oh boy, I was there in one of the Hassidic courts in Jerusalem. This is far from guidance, that's the full submission we're talking about. What you told is exactly the spirit - "if you miss doing a positive mitzvah you are never able to fix it". People are led to believe that without the Rebbe they are lost. They can't connect to God, they can't fix themselves, as they are not pious and holy enough. Well, it's your life and your choices.

@AlBerko I don't know what the role of a Rebbe has to do with this, but the irreparable loss of forgoing a mitzvah is from Chagigah 9b: תניא נמי הכי מעוות לא יוכל לתקון זה שביטל קרית שמע של שחרית או קריאת שמע של ערבית או שביטל תפלה של שחרית או תפלה של ערבית וחסרון לא יוכל להימנות זה שנמנו חביריו לדבר מצוה והוא לא נמנה עמהן

@shmosel Welcome, I'm glad you joined. I accept the Gemmora as a "fact" - surely, like in Mario, if you miss a reward it vanishes (never played, though) - for some Mitzvos you don't get to compensate for the miss. But let's observe the difference in the psychology of how it is presented to the masses - in the mainstream (say Litvakes or Sefardi) Judaism, it's just a game - you miss this one, next time prepare ahead. But in BeSHT's Hassidism, it leaves "an irreparable hole in your soul" that (as David testified) "only the [clinging to the] Rebbe could atone".

I'm not judging Hassidism, I'm trying to describe my perspective as a former Hassidic Ba'al Teshuva who experienced this personally.

I don't believe there's any branch of mainstream Judaism that would call violating a positive commandment "just a game." It requires teshuva just like a negative commandment. This gemara takes it a step further: even after teshuva, the lost opportunity is lost forever. You can do the mitzvah tomorrow, but you'll never have another chance to fulfill today's mitzvah.

In any case, it's not an innovation of chassidus that violating a mitzvah damages the soul. And the notion that it can be repaired by clinging to the Rebbe is unsubstantiated hearsay from OP that you've turned into the basis for a pointless polemic against chassidim. I would expect a former chassidic BT to be better informed about chassidic philosophy.

@AlBerko (following on shmosel's last point): particularly since, before you even commented, I already summarized the passages that he had referenced, which don't mention the slightest thing about a rebbe, just about a more powerful level of teshuvah and of reconnection to Hashem.

@shmosel Let's not discuss me, but the sources. You can't "violate" a positive Mitzva, you can only miss it. So you move on, that's all. I'd like to have a non-Kabbalistic source that missing a positive Mitzvah damages the soul. He wrote, "although our teacher said although if you connected to a Rebbe... doesn't it contradict the Iggeres?. I see the teacher's words as a crucial claim. Did I understand the question wrong?

@AlBerko "You can't violate a positive Mitzva"? Sure it's possible to. The Gemara (Yoma 86a) uses the same word, עבר, for positive and prohibitory mitzvos. || Yes, the OP wrote that. It's still unsubstantiated, so rather than seeing it as a "crucial claim," first consider whether there's any validity to it.

@Meir Right, like "עבר על דברי המלך" you mean? Some suggested that missing a positive Mitzva entails "violating king's law". But I meant the Peshat - there's no punishment for such a "violation" you just don't get rewarded. isn't it?

@AlBerko Just because there's no punishment doesn't mean much. There isn't one for many prohibitory mitzvos either.

Bris milah and Korban Pesach are punishable by kareis
